# What's win32con module in python? Where can I find it?

Tags: python, module

I'm building an open source project that uses python and c++ in Windows.
I came to the following error message:

```
 ImportError: No module named win32con
```

The same happened in a "prebuilt" code that it's working ( except in my computer :P )

I think this is kind of "popular" module in python because I've saw several messages in other forums but none that could help me.

I have Python2.6, should I have that module already installed?
Is that something of VC++?

Thank you for the help.

I got this url http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/  but I'm not sure what to do with the executable :S

Comment: See the [Python Programming On Win32](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926219/) for details on this package.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This module contains constants related to Win32 programming.  It is not part of the Python 2.6 release, but should be part of the download of the pywin32 project.

**Edit:** I imagine that the executable is an installation program, though the last time I downloaded pywin32 it was just a zip file.

Comment: Ok, so it is something common. There are .exe files and yes a zip file.

Answer (score 57):

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

[Glyph](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com) had packed packed it until somebody sends patch to build wheels as part of `pywin32` build process to close https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/680/

Comment: When I try to run this I get the following error: "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)" - I'm running Python 2.7.10, do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: @MACC no idea. Perhaps your connection is down or your system is not Windows. Because `pywin32==223` is there - https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files

Comment: **WARNING:** [“Pypiwin32 is an old and outdated repackaging of pywin32 from its creator to use wheels. It is abandoned for a long time. You should just use pywin32.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55918399/4877269)

Answer (score 11):

If you have pywin32 installed you can do in python 3.7+

```
import win32.lib.win32con as win32con
```

Answer (score 8):

Ok I stumbled here twice for installs on two machines so here is a quick link for that ressource

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/

This is the actual download page of the project and now a readme download

Comment: It's currently here: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32

Answer (score 2):

Note that the [Pywin32 download](http://sourceforge.net/project/platformdownload.php?group_id=78018) page contains installers for version 2.6 (i386 and AMD64). The [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/Products/activepython/feature_list.mhtml) distribution is a *single installer that includes pywin32* - currently at version 2.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

The PyWin32 download references including project references are found in the [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) registry.

Answer (score -2):

navigate to: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib and copy the win32con.py file into your project directory.