# is there a module that enables property editing for general windows files

Tags: python, properties, hidden

so recently, a technologically clever fellow hid all the files in my school's most frequently accessed and most important public networked mounted drives.

now, as the problem hasn't yet been fixed, i see it as an opportunity to expand my knowledge on python. I would like if there is a module that allows me to edit the properties of files in folders in general. !!EDIT: Windows folders.

not the /contents/, the properties. like the date/time accessed, images of mp3 music, and more importantly, the hidden/not hidden status of files.

Comment: Right click on the folder, select properties, and uncheck the hidden check box. In other words do the same as this evil genius did originally.

Comment: i was talking in terms of making a program do it. automatically. perhaps i should have specified that. (and i mean a module that would allow me to make a program to do it)

Comment: This link discusses the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549109/hide-folders-file-with-python

Comment: @dan30484 I don't think it does. The link covers hiding a file, but OP is asking for how to edit properties in the general case.

Comment: You could write such a program to do this task.  Why would you do so? It already exists.

Comment: @David, I believe the author gave the reason as "i see it as an opportunity to expand my knowledge on python".

Comment: Micheal's got it right, mostly. the reason i want to write a program to do it is because i can use that module and that knowledge to do other things in the future.

Comment: OK. So pick a topic to ask. Your question covers enumerating files, file system attributes and meta data. Three very different topics. Pick one. Then do some research and ask a question if you get stuck. Anyway, asking for a library recommendation is off topic here. I do think you need to refine your question somewhat.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1512435/646543) might be useful, though it doesn't look like there's any simple solution or library to what you're asking, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/download/windows) package to access a wide range of Windows API's. In particular, the [SetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function will be useful. You can see [an example here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303343-changing-file-attributes-on-windows/). There are other API's such as GetFileAttributes and GetFileAttributesEx to can use to get more information. they'll be defined in the same place as SetFileAttributes.