# Ctypes: cannot import windll

Tags: python, ctypes

I am running Python 2.7 32bits (Anaconda) on Windows 7 64bits.

I would like to use ctypes to do win32 API calls, and I have a very weird issue: I can `import ctypes`, but not `import ctypes.windll`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named windll
```

I have crawled the web and SO but I didn't find anything similar to my issue (it's either about impossibility of importing ctypes at all, or a bug in the DLL you try to import).

Has anyone an idea of what I did wrong?

Answer (score 6):

It appears you cannot just `import ctypes.windll`, you need to `import ctypes` and then use `ctypes.windll`. I discovered that by printing all properties of ctypes:

```
import ctypes
print dir(ctypes)
```

What's also interesting is that IPython autocompletion was misleading here, because it didn't show `windll` as a possible choice when TAB-autocompleting after `import ctypes.`.

Comment: Bear in mind that using `ctypes.windll` leaves you at the mercy of any module that happens to load the same DLL and set the prototype (`restype`, `argtypes`, `errcheck`) on a function that you're also calling. The function pointer instance is cached on the `WinDLL` instance which is cached on `windll`, so you can get conflicts with how you're defining the types and `errcheck` function compared with what another user has defined. You're better off in the long run calling `ctypes.WinDLL` to get an instance that's specific to your module or script.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you very much for the tip!

Comment: To bounce on eryksun's comment: you cannot directly call `ctypes.WinDLL.kernel32`, you need to do the following: `from ctypes import LibraryLoader; windll = LibraryLoader(ctypes.WinDLL)`, then you can call `windll.kernel32` without having the redefinition issues that eryksun mentioned.

Comment: You don't call `windll.kernel32`. You get a function pointer instance as an attribute, e.g. `windll.kernel32.CreateFileW`. The other problem with using the loader is that it doesn't let you pass the argument `use_last_error=True`, which is used in tandem with `ctypes.get_last_error()` and `ctypes.set_last_error()`. I recommend that you use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)`.

Comment: Then when a function fails that's documented on MSDN to set the last error value you can get a nicely formatted exception using `raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())`.