# NameError: global name 'windll' is not defined

Tags: python, linux

i am running a python(2.7) file on linux(raspbian).
file runs fine until it tries to load a library.

Running LINUX. Not Windows.
i have executed this program on a windows machine and it works with no problems.

full error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "mainMsg.py", line 42, in
>
> instance = PCANBasic()
>
> File "/home/pi/Alexa/PCANBasic.py", line 242, in **init**
>
> self.__m_dllBasic = windll.LoadLibrary("PCANBasic")
>
> NameError: global name 'windll' is not defined

I am aware that the problem may be because of windows only libraries? I'm looking for a solution to allow my code to run on linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ctypes: cannot import windll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040123/ctypes-cannot-import-windll)

Comment: i then get the error: AttributeError: module 'ctypes' has no atttribute 'windll'

Comment: windll is only available on Windows.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to allow my code to run on linux. (i am aware it is only available on windows: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.WinDLL)

Comment: The solution is porting it.

Comment: how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error and process it.

```
try:
    instance = PCANBasic()
except NameError:
    pass          # replace it whatever you want to do when this error occurs.
```

rest of the stuff