# how to modify txt file properties with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python program that creates and writes in a txt file.
the program works, but I want it to cross the "hidden" thing in the txt file's properties, so that the txt can't be seen without using the python program I made. I have no clues how to do that, please understand I am a beginner in python.

Comment: If you want it to only be used by your python program you should consider putting it in zip and password protecting it. Hiding it is simple but it won't really protect your file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I don't think you can do this in Python. I'd suggest finding a simple Visual Basic script and running it from your Python file.

Comment: ok thanks for trying to help. I can't use a visual basic script I have to only use python

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the file-properties, where you can [set a file as "hidden"](https://www.howtogeek.com/194671/how-to-hide-files-and-folders-on-every-operating-system/). Like in *Windows* as seen in screenshot below:

[image: set the file-property 'hidden' in Windows]

#### Use operating-system's command-line from Python

For example in Windows command-line `attrib +h Secret_File.txt` to [hide a file in CMD](https://www.wikihow.com/Hide-Files-in-Cmd).

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["attrib", "+h", "Secret_File.txt"])
```

See also:
[How to execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command)

#### Directly call OS functions (Windows)

```py
import ctypes

path = "my_hidden_file.txt"
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(path, 2)
```

See also:
[Hide Folders/ File with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549109/hide-folders-file-with-python)

#### Rename the file (Linux)

```py
import os

filename = "my_hidden_file.txt"
os.rename(filename, '.'+filename)  # the prefix dot means hidden in Linux
```

See also:
[How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)