# Why does pip install winshell not work on Python v3.4.2?

Tags: python, pip, python-winshell

Install winshell with pip:

```
C:\Users\jonc>pip install winshell
Downloading/unpacking winshell
  Downloading winshell-0.6.zip
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\winshell\setup.py) egg_info for package winshell

Installing collected packages: winshell
  Running setup.py install for winshell

Successfully installed winshell
Cleaning up...
```

Try and import it:

```
C:\Users\jonc>python
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import winshell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\winshell.py", line 30, in <module>
    import win32con
ImportError: No module named 'win32con'
```

Why does this fail?

Pip version is as follows:

```
C:\Users\jonc>pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Comment: Looks as though the `win32con` dependency isn't installed.

Comment: you need to install [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) manually (can't be installed using pip)

Comment: That's frustrating (that it can't be installed via pip) :(

Comment: Looks like I'm not the first to have similar issues: https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/680/

Answer (score 1):

you will need to install [pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywin32/) to get the missing file.
it must be installed separately (i.e. it cannot be installed with pip).  for more information see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227928/whats-win32con-module-in-python-where-can-i-find-it).

Comment: If you add that it needs to be manually installed (i.e. installing via PIP doesn't work) I'll accept this as the answer.