# Python module imports on windows 10

Tags: python, import, module, windows-10

I am currently building a desktop app and recently noticed that there are issues with importing modules on Win 10.

For example, running the following on Win 7 **without python installed** works:

```
import win32con
```

But running it on a Win 10 machine **without python installed** yields:

```
No module named 'win32con'
```

This is just an example; there are many other modules which throw an **ImportError** when ran on Win10 but work on Win7, both without Python installed

Of course, running *pip install* on Win10 installs the module, but my goal is to have the app run on Win10 without having Python installed to run *pip install*.

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: How are you running python code without having python installed?

Comment: How can you run the app on Win 10 if python is not installed? Do  build the app into a .exe before running it?

Comment: I am sorry for omitting this. Yes, I am using an .exe built with pyinstaller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's win32con module in python? Where can I find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227928/whats-win32con-module-in-python-where-can-i-find-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using **cx_Freeze** instead of **pyinstaller** to build the package.