# Unable to create combobox in Python 2.5

Tags: python, user-interface, pywin32

I am trying to create a combobox using the following code

```
    s = cs | win32con.WS_BORDER | win32con.WS_TABSTOP | win32con.WS_VSCROLL | win32con.CBS_DROPDOWN | win32con.CBS_AUTOHSCROLL
    dlg.append([130, "Comments", -1, (7, y-6, 60, 9), cs])
    dlg.append([128, None, win32ui.IDC_COMBO1, (70, 20, 200, 10),s])
```

I get only a greyed out space without any dropdownlist

I am using Win32 as my GUI builder

Kindly help

Comment: Do you mean you are using [win32con](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227928/whats-win32con-module-in-python-where-can-i-find-it#227930) or pywin32 as your GUI builder? Also, please show a complete code snippet that we can copy-and-paste into our editors and run. The code you show is out-of-context and not runnable.

Comment: Yes I am using win32con

Comment: How do I get the dropdown

Comment: what other parameters I have to add

Comment: I cannot speak for everyone here, but I (along with some others) refuse to answer this question until you show a *complete* code example. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to follow those requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change has to be here

```
    dlg.append([5, None, win32ui.IDC_COMBO1, (70, 20, 200, 10),s])
```