# Python not recognizing win32con

Tags: python

I asked an earlier question about how I could detect whether a window was minimized or not and got this code for the answer:

```
window = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", None)
if window:
    tup = win32gui.GetWindowPlacement(window)
    if tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED:
        minimized = False
    elif tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWMINIMIZED:
        minimized = True
    elif tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL:
        normal = True
```

As I am sure it works, the problem is that I cannot figure out how to get "win32con" to work. I have tried pip installs, imports, and everything that goes along with it and I still get the error:

```
NameError: name 'win32con' is not defined
```

How can I resolve this error and properly import win32con?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `import win32con`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't exist or come up

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you receive an import error?

Comment: unresolved import

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's win32con module in python? Where can I find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227928/whats-win32con-module-in-python-where-can-i-find-it)

Answer (score 1):

Took a bit of searching but I have an answer for you.

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

I also had to manually type in my imports because my IDE (Pycharm) could not make the link between win32gui and pypiwin32. I've also added some print statements so I could see if it was actually working.

```
import win32gui
import win32con

window = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", None)
if window:
    tup = win32gui.GetWindowPlacement(window)
    if tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED:
        minimized = False
        print('MAX')
    elif tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWMINIMIZED:
        minimized = True
        print('MIN')
    elif tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL:
        normal = True
        print('NORMAL')
```