# Spyder: no module named pywintypes

Tags: python, spyder, pywin32, win32com

My Spyder python version is 3.7.9.
I tried to run `import win32com.client as win32` then I got the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-360eab2b8977>", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client as win32

  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\win32com\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pythoncom

  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'
```

I looked at the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes) and copy and pasted files as below. In my case, I copied (pythoncom38.dll + pywintypes38.dll + pythoncom37.dll and pywintypes37.dll) but still I am getting the same error

[image]

Comment: Try this:
import win32.lib.win32con as win32con Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227928/whats-win32con-module-in-python-where-can-i-find-it

Comment: sorry slightly confused here. How do get the `Dispatch` function afterwards ? Normally I would do `from win32com.client import Dispatch` but now it would just complain no module named pywintypes.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.
So, I try to remove the Spyder and re-install the Spyder via CMD then run win32com to open excel.

- CMD input the command:

1. pip install wheel
2. pip install spyder
3. spyder

[Sample open excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BcQh.png)